# Second stage low-pass filter intuition

Tags: pcb, frequency, low-pass, frequency-response

I am attempting to make a two-stage RC low-pass filter. I have increased the impedance at the second stage in order to have a lower loading effect on the first stage.

I noticed that once the circuit is connected, using a multimeter across the output capacitor, the second stage capacitor should be 0.22 μF but it shows the value is 22 μF similar to the first stage. Is there any reason for that? Would that affect the frequency response of the circuit?

First stage:
R1 = 20 Ω
C1 = 22 μF

Second stage:
R2 = 2 kΩ
C2 = 0.22 μF (shows 22 μF using multimeter)

This in turn affected the frequency response of my circuit; it had a negative slope and is linear.

Comment: Try removing C2 and re-measuring <-- I bet you still see 22 uF.

Comment: In other words, "measuring" a 22 uF capacitor via a 2 kohm resistor still might result in the meter registering 22 uF. If it doesn't then try adding a 100 nF capacitor instead of the 220 nF and see what happens. It's a meter phenomena I suspect.